# How can I compute categorical accuracy after I predict the results in Keras model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, metrics

I have built a Keras model and **while training**, the categorical accuracy metric reaches 0.78.

However after training the model, when I **predict** the output of same training data when I run the following code:

```
predicted_labels = model.predict(input_data)
acc = sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(true_labels, predicted_labels)
```

the accuracy is 0.39.
To summarize, I don't get same accuracy result for Keras and Sklearn.

Comment: Why didn't you use model.predict_classes(input_data) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of measuring accuracy, and sklearn might not be using the same as Keras.

You may take your compiled model and `lossAndMetrics = model.evaluate(input_data, true_labels)` to see loss and metrics that are surely the same you used for training.

PS: it's not rare to have a bad result for test/validation data if your model is overfitting.